# Sleep() function windows 8 c++

Tags: c++, windows-8, header, undefined, sleep

I'm attempting to get the Sleep() function working on a Windows 8 operating system, with c++. So far I haven't found any examples specific to this.

Following from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx i've included the header `<Synchapi.h>`, though i get "Identifier "Sleep" is undefined". I am able to find the functions SleepConditionVariableCS() and SleepConditionVariableSRW() from Synchapi.h, but not Sleep().

Has anyone managed to use Sleep() on a Windows 8 operating system or know why I am unable to find the function?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be including Synchapi.h directly. Include Windows.h instead.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  Sleep(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using C++11? If you are you can use:

```
#include <thread>
template< class Rep, class Period >
void sleep_for( const std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>& sleep_duration );
```

**Update**
The Sleep() function is only available for Desktop Apps. Are you building a formerly known as Metro app? Or an App Store app?
See this article for some work arounds:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/11/28/introduce-multi-thread-programming-in-windows-store-apps-part-ii.aspx

Comment: ah that would be why (I am building a Metro app). The alternative looks quite a bit more complex.